# Can a only-movable object be made into a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, packaged-task

I am reading open source code of [thread_pool](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)

And it shows

```
// add new work item to the pool
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
            std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );
        
    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

        // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
        if(stop)
            throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");

        tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); });
    }
    condition.notify_one();
    return res;
}
```

As far as I know,  `std::packaged_task` is a only movable object, so could a shared_ptr of `task` be made of `std::packaged_task`?Because `std::packaged_task` could never be `shared`.

But in an oppisite way, in sentence `tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); });`, `task` is value-copied into lambda, so does it also mean the count in shared_ptr of `task` will be added into 2?Which means `std::packaged_task` is actually be `shared` into 2 copies.

So can a only-movable object be made into a shared_ptr?Are there any wrong place in my above thoughts?

Comment: Pointer to any type can be put in shared_ptr. Why does it surprise you?

Comment: Try to separate the pointers qualifiers from the pointed-to object qualifiers (doesn't matter if smart or raw pointer). Be it `const`-ness, singelton-ness, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smart pointers don't even need the element type to be movable. They never attempt to make any copies in any form. All `make_shared` does is construct an object once and then `shared_ptr` just pass around a pointer to that single object.

Copying a `shared_ptr` is just like copying a raw pointer (plus the reference counting of course). It doesn't make a copy of the pointed-to object.

You wouldn't need the type to be copyable or movable either if all you did manually was to use `new` to create it once and then work through (copies of) the resulting raw pointer.